When will an optional property in `chrome.history.HistoryItem` be undefined?
Here is how it is defined in @types/chrome:
    /** An object encapsulating one result of a history query. */
    export interface HistoryItem {
        /** Optional. The number of times the user has navigated to this page by typing in the address. */
        typedCount?: number | undefined;
        /** Optional. The title of the page when it was last loaded. */
        title?: string | undefined;
        /** Optional. The URL navigated to by a user. */
        url?: string | undefined;
        /** Optional. When this page was last loaded, represented in milliseconds since the epoch. */
        lastVisitTime?: number | undefined;
        /** Optional. The number of times the user has navigated to this page. */
        visitCount?: number | undefined;
        /** The unique identifier for the item. */
        id: string;
    }

I don't understand why there are so many optional properties, I've never seen onVisited missing these properties in my actual applications.
I suspect that what onVisited carries is actually Required<chrome.history.HistoryItem>. When are they really optional?
I used indexeddb to record all my history for a day and did not see any records with missing optional properties.

Chrome uses separate databases for visits (with url id inside) and for the actual urls. Judging by the source code they may be out of sync or missing data.
